# How to enter BIOS on UEFI capable Lenovo Z50? (Novo button)

Tags: uefi, bios

I have a Lenovo Z50 machine that came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I booted into Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit from a DVD using the "Change Advanced Startup Options" (or similar) option from within Windows to boot into the DVD. Then, I installed Ubuntu, overwriting Windows completely. I have the following parititions:

- efi (50 MiB)
- / (100 GiB)
- swap (8 GiB)
- /home (remaining space of the 1 TiB hard disk)

**The installation is perfectly fine, but now I am not able to access my BIOS.** Googling around for the issue revealed answers pertaining to dual-boot scenarios, assuming the asker had Windows installed along-side Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: This isn't an Ubuntu question unfortunately.  Try pressing shutting down the computer, and then pressing the "Novo" button, which is a small button near the power connector.  I got this from a manual here: http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_series_ug_english.pdf

Comment: @user7134 Thank you. It worked like a charm. Can you please post it as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: **Dear Reviewers:** If you vote for off-topic then please name the SE instance where it is actually more on-topic and take actions to help migrating it there. On the other side, the question was answered perfectly fine and we can point the next user that will surely ask a very similar question to this answer here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't really an Ubuntu related question though.

According to [the manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_series_ug_english.pdf) on page 7 (actually 13 in the document):

> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Press the **Novo** button and then select **BIOS Setup**.

On this model it is a small button near the power connector:

[image]