# Ubuntu won't boot up properly (Toshiba Satellite P50)

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-8, uefi

So I recently switched out windows 8 for Ubuntu on my Toshiba laptop. I installed it from my usb and everything went fine. Ubuntu was on my comp and I stupidly spent a few hours personalizing it and installing my favorite programs. Then I restarted the comp. Now, the only way Ubuntu will boot is if the usb is in. Not only that but it goes right back to the bare bones Ubuntu and not my personalized version. Before it boots the same black screen comes up and asks if I want to try Ubuntu or install it and I have to hit either one just to get into the system. If the usb is not in the comp then nothing boots up. Ubuntu should already be installed onto my comp. How do I switch the OS from on the usb to permanently on my hard drive? It is not an issue with boot order. I have already played around and changed order up a few times.

Comment: Okay, when you "installed" it, you didn't actually install. You clicked try it. It is still the live USB. Try clicking install when it boots up http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Nope I def didn't hit "try" I hit install. I wanted to permanently install and it did just fine. Just now when I boot it does not work

Comment: Hmm, does the answer below work? I don't think it will..

Comment: Could you please post the output of `mount && sudo parted --list && sudo apt-get install -y efibootmgr && sudo efibootmgr -v` and [edit] your question? Photos of the firmware settings would also be helpful. According to the [manual on page 60](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/manuals/userguides/su4001474/GMAD00351010_Sat-SatPro-P70-P50-P40-A_Series_12May17.pdf) the key to access the boot menu is F12. Accessing the BIOS/firmware settings should be available through this key.

Comment: Explanation: `mount` should show mounted efi system variables (if the current system is started in UEFI mode), `parted` existing partition tables (there should be an ESP) and `efibootmgr` existing NVRAM entries (e.g. is the previous installation was done in UEFI mode). For installation on a UEFI machine the live media should be booted and installation be done in UEFI mode. http://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581

Comment: I was not able to copy and paste all of the output but it said Partition table: gpt. efibootmgr is already newest version. efibootmgr set to manually installed. 0 ugraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 217 not ugraded. There is way too much more output to fully describe to you. Is there a way I can send you a link of it?

Comment: After typing in above command, it output "Partition table: gpt. efibootmgr is already newest version. disk /dev/sda2 750GB. Sector size 512B." There is way too much more output to copy and paste in here. Is there a way to copy a link to you?

Comment: Sorry, last two of my comments were kind of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Some systems shipping with Windows 8 have trouble booting Ubuntu the way it is currently implemented for UEFI machines.

You could try booting the live USB again and follow my instructions from this Q&A:
[UEFI machine doesn't boot Ubuntu through NVRAM bootcatalog. How to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/549647/40581)

Regarding the customization, if you haven't successfully booted Ubuntu from the hard drive before, these changes were lost during the reboot.

Please post the model of the computer you are using to help analyzing this issue further.

Comment: I don't know if that is the answer. I am not using duel-boot either I already successfully installed Ubuntu and wiped out windows. Ubuntu will still boot just only with the usb in. I really think its just a boot order issue and I want to try that first before other things but I can't figure out how to change the boot order on Linux. Don't know how to access advanced boot options or BIOS. Everything I tried doesn't work

Comment: @PatDoyle I already understood that you removed Windows, but I wouldn't have suggested this answer if it could be misleading. If you still have an EFI system partition and a GPT partition table the answer should work.

Comment: I typed the commands in from the link you  provided and I got the message "EFI system partitions found but none appear to be mounted: please enter the device name of your ESP:" I don't know where to find the name of the ESP. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, my comp is a fairly new Toshiba Satellite P50 if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. The script should have listed existing partitions with FAT32 filesystem, like in the example output. It's strange if it didn't do that (probably no EFI System Partition). The Toshiba Satellite P50 seems to be a mid to high-end class device from 2014, that's interesting and unexpected. That you wiped Windows however makes some things a bit more diffcult and I personally wouldn't recommend it, even if you don't use Windows.

Comment: So mysteriously my comp and Ubuntu just boot up without USB in. It looks like everything is running good and it didn't ask me to "try" or "install". I typed in the same commands from the (short answer) from the link you posted above and now the output says: "The following device appears to be mounted as an EFI system partition - /dev/sda1 Is that correct? Yes or no. Note that answering no will unmount /dev/sda1" I didn't pick yes or no I just left it. Also, the boot order is currently set to USB first then HDD second, but it still boot without USB in

Comment: I changed boot order to do HDD first and everything boots properly every time I restart. How can I check if this is permanent and all settings/updates/programs will be saved for future use? The only thing I have changed in terms of settings is the desktop background and it is still there every time I re-boot. Seems to be a good sign

Comment: @PatDoyle That's good news. You don't need to run anymore troubleshooting. :) From what you described the script from my other answer didn't ran successfully, which is a bit confusing. Could you post the output of `ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/boot/` – which just lists directory contents – by editing your question through the edit link, please? If there is a `grub.cfg` there, than the script actually ran successfully once.

Comment: When I run that script, it comes back "cannot access, not such file or directory"

Comment: I just want to make sure somehow that this is going to be permanent and the OS to work properly/quickly. Especially with updates. If im working on something and can't find files because they weren't actually saved I will def freak out. So far everything looks ok, so thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

First enter your bios and change the bootup sequence to something like this:
1. Harddisk
2. CD-rom
3. USB
4. etc..

Then during boot press F12 to enter the one-time Boot menue!
Otherwise your USB-stick will be named SDA that should be your (Primary) harddisk.
Try that.

Comment: Thanks. I keep reading to press various keys during bootup to get into that advanced settings menu but its not working! So frustrating. I checked my hard drive and the system is def on there, so that makes me think its some kind of boot order issue or somethinig with partitions? Your answer is helpful and I've been trying to get in there to change boot order but no luck yet

Comment: And how do I get into bios? Also, I don't know the commands if it involves any of that. I was hoping for options I can just change if need be

Comment: When you boot your computer, you can press a key. Normally F12, F2, Esc, F8 or Del. The BIOS does not change when you install Ubuntu.

Comment: I was finally able to get into BIOS and switch the boot order but sadly that still did not make Ubuntu boot properly on its own when I restarted. I made my HDD first in the order hoping that I would be able to boot without the usb from then on.

Comment: @PatDoyle This is sort of what I expected and I think we can fix or work around this issue once I know all the details about the current state.