# UEFI boot up file for Ubuntu? (Toshiba P840t-ST3N01)

Tags: uefi, 14.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Toshiba P840t-ST3N01 and I keep getting the following message: `Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key`.

I want to install 14.10 Ubuntu from a USB I have. It boots up fine, but when I install, it says it is installed, but can't boot up. Also tried boot-repair. It tells me to boot from the file `sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` though, so how do I do it?

1 terabyte hard drive, windows 8 deleted. UEFI mode enabled.

Comment: Try F12 at powerup, then select HDD, then ubuntu to boot.

Comment: Some vendors modify UEFI internally to only boot the entry with "Windows" in it. If you have only Ubuntu you can change the grub or shim to read Windows with efibootmgr and it should then boot. See D: which shows shim but could also be grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Others have also used some of the other work arounds. To see efi entries: modprobe efivars then:
sudo efibootmgr -v run from terminal in live install booted in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: This sounds alot more like a I destroyed my Grub how do I fix it.

Comment: @Tim No, I have wanted to install Ubuntu replacing Windows 8. By that, I mean formatting the drive and installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu, not dual boot.

Comment: to get it working in UEFI mode I suggest trying the following solution from a live session: http://askubuntu.com/a/549648/40581

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues before installing Ubuntu on a UEFI system. For me the issue was simple, I had to disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and FastStartup (for Windows 8) from the BIOS before installation. If you haven't done that I would recommend to try it. If however you still have that problem, then you may find more information here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried that, but I do not know how to partition the drive to make Ubuntu start. I have put a swap(250mb), 2 ext4's (one 300gb, other 699gb), but I don't understand about the efi partition, there is also a  efi boot partition selection, can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out an answer to my problem! I had to boot my laptop into CSM mode, legacy, and install Ubuntu from there. Before, it said that a file was not found, but if I press tab then, I can locate the file and run it from there. It has fixed my problem and Ubuntu can boot up the hard drive from there.