# Kubuntu erased whole disk while trying to install in EFI mode

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, kubuntu, acer

I just bought a laptop Acer Aspire V11 (500 GB hardrive, 4GB RAM) with Windows 8 installed on it.

I want to replace Windows with Kubuntu.

I set the boot order to USB and created a bootable USB with Kubuntu 14.04 iso on it to install.

When I boot from the USB it looks like it is using EFI mode (black screen with only 3 options).

At the Disk setup step I chose to use all disk available for Kubuntu
Once the installation finished the computer cannot boot Kubuntu. Windows has been completely erased.

It looks like the Kubuntu installation has erased all the partitions and now the computer is not even able to boot on the hard drive.

Should I make a specific partition scheme?  Is this something to do with the EFI?

Comment: Also when i boot by hammering the F12 in the boot manager there is
not boot option available

Comment: Also in the Bios when i change the boot option UEFI to legacy
the problem is still there "PXE-M0F : exiting PXE ROM
No bootable device"

Comment: Some more informations:
While booting from the live version of my Kubuntu USB
i have installed Gparted to have a look how Kubuntu have sliced my HD
here the result:
partition  file system      size       flags
/dev/sda1  FAT32            512 MiB     boot
/dev/sda2   ext4            235.15 GB
/dev/sda4   ext4            226 GB
/dev/sda3   linux swap       3.88 GB
unallocated                  1.02MiB

Comment: I have run the Boot-repair tool with the live USB to try to fix my boot problem.
Here the link of the report http://paste.ubuntu.com/9512595/
Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. When i stop the computer, remove the boot USB and restart computer i fall back with a No Bootable Device.
Hopefully someone can help me with these informations

Comment: Please update your own question with the new data instead of using comments for this.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new stick with Ubuntu 14.04

In Bios Boot option I changed to legacy boot for HDD

Then from the live Ubuntu I started the install option
and chose *Something Else* to do manual partitioning

Installed GRUB to `/dev/sda` (I think the first time I did `/dev/sda1` which may explain why it was not booting)

Primary partition Ext4, mount point `/` with all space less 4 GB (my RAM)
Logical partition as Swap with 4 GB

That's all. I will install Kubuntu desktop from here.

Comment: Many vendors are modifying UEFI to only boot an entry with Windows in it. So you have to do a work around to make it think it is booting Windows. If only running Ubuntu you just change the ubuntu entry in UEFI to read Windows with efibootmgr and that will work. See option D: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789  Some also rename /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi which Ubuntu installer may not even add now, but you can. http://askubuntu.com/questions/549647/uefi-machine-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-through-nvram-bootcatalog-how-to-fix