# How do I get Ubuntu grub to recognize dual boot

Tags: grub2, mint

I have Ubuntu loaded on my sda partition, Mint on my sdd. Ubuntu's Grub isn't seeing that Mint is installed, so I can't boot it. How do I fix Grub so I can boot into either one?

What is the correct way to dual boot ubuntu & mint?

Comment: We only support official releases of Ubuntu. Mint is not one of them.

Comment: does `sudo update-grub` doesn't work?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off topic because 1) Contains more of a question relating to Grub, than Ubuntu, and 2) Refers to a question about Linux Mint, which is not supported on this site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install multiple Linux Distros and Windows 8 on UEFI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/563077/how-to-install-multiple-linux-distros-and-windows-8-on-uefi)  (That should help)

Answer (score 1):

**Using a live Ubuntu cd** 
And running boot-repair should fix the issue.

After you have loaded the live cd in "try mode".

open a terminal (ctl alt t)
Then run the following command one by one to install the boot repair.
Add boot-repair to the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Update the package

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Upgarde and run.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade &&  boot-repair
```

**Or select it by System->Aministration->Boot Repair.**