# Dual-Boot(Ubuntu/ArchLinux ): configure Ubuntu's GRUB2 to boot both OS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, os-prober

I have ArchLinux installed with NON-UEFI ***(since last edit its UEFI now)*** on /*dev/sda4* partitioned with LVM2 containing two logical volumes *(/vgarch/arch_root & /vgarch/arch_home)* , since i have GRUB2 installed by Ubuntu 22.04 i want to configure it to detect ArchLinux,mounting */dev/vgarch/arch_root* and running `update-grub` (else os-prob won't detect idk why) gave me the following output

```
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for ya22y: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Found Arch Linux on /dev/mapper/vgarch-arch_root
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

GRUB shows ArchLinux entry but when i boot i got error saying

> error: file "/vmlinuz-linux-lts" not found

However the kernel is installed. ( and tried to reinstall it from live environment)

```
$ sudo mount /dev/vgarch/arch_root /mnt
$ sudo chroot /mnt
[root@IYB /]# ls /boot
initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img  initramfs-linux-lts.img  vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

Tried to add ArchLinux entry manually by adding the following script to /*etc/grub.d/40_custom*

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux' {
                                          #UUID of /dev/vgarch/arch_root partition
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c rw
        initrd /boot/initramfs.linux-lts.img }
```

booting to 'Arch Linux' gave the following:

> error: uknown filesystem

**Additional details**

***/dev/sda***

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238,47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: LITEON LMH-256V2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7B055726-9B69-4E1B-9DD6-4762B556617D

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1054720 233877503 232822784  111G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  233877504 500117503 266240000  127G Linux LVM
```

***Logical volumes***

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgarch/arch_root
  LV Name                arch_root
  VG Name                vgarch
  LV UUID                yhsMld-G8Zp-h6au-pfZw-k3V1-EkuT-Wgyf5A
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time archiso, 2023-09-19 23:22:59 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                16,00 GiB
  Current LE             4096
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgarch/arch_home
  LV Name                arch_home
  VG Name                vgarch
  LV UUID                cwlwYH-FXu4-zU3n-yHsL-DkSo-Gsl8-uRkuLE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time archiso, 2023-09-19 23:24:11 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <110,95 GiB
  Current LE             28403
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

***/boot directory in Arch***

```
ya22y@IYB:~$ sudo mount /dev/vgarch/arch_root /mnt
ya22y@IYB:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
[root@IYB /]# ls /boot
initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img  initramfs-linux-lts.img  vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

***Arch directory /etc/mkinitcpio.conf***

i've ran mkinitcpio -P after adding lvm2.

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf kms keyboard keymap consolefont block lvm2 filesystems fsck)
```

***EDIT***
I have installed grub from ArchLinux to ESP partition a.k.a `/dev/sda2`, and update it using `grub-mkconfig`.
Now i hade two booting options,ubuntu_grub and arch_grub.
However none of the grub associatiated with niether ubuntu or arch seems to detect the other OS.(os-prober enabled).

***booting from ubuntu_grub..***
Ubuntu OS appears and i can boot into it, however going to grub rescue mode and trying to `ls (lvm/vgarch-arch_root)` results

***booting from arch_grub..***
its get me directly to grub rescue mode, however try to `ls (lvm/vgarch-arch_root)` and `ls (hd,gpt3)` seems to recognize both OS filesystems.

> "no known filesystem".

**Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary:**

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/grub_arch/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on sda3
OS#2:   Arch Linux (rolling) on mapper/vgarch-arch_root

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A17(65.17) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 000F
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 000C,000A,000B,000D,000E,0001,0000,0002,0009,000F
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2,0x1000,0x100800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* GRUB  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(1,65535,0)/HD(2,GPT,b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2,0x1000,0x100800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0002* grub_arch HD(2,GPT,b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2,0x1000,0x100800)/File(\EFI\grub_arch\grubx64.efi)
Boot0009* UEFI: LITEON LMH-256V2M-11 MSATA 256GB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(1,65535,0)/HD(2,GPT,b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2,0x1000,0x100800)AMBO
Boot000A* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)AMBO
Boot000B* Internal HDD  BBS(HD,P1: LITEON LMH-256V2M-11 MSATA,0x0)AMBO
Boot000C* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,ADATA USB Flash Drive 0.00,0x0)AMBO
Boot000D* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)AMBO
Boot000E* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,IBA GE Slot 00C8 v1550,0x0)AMBO
Boot000F* UEFI: ADATA USB Flash Drive 0.00  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(2,GPT,f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0,0x95f864,0x2754)AMBO

a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda2/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/BOOT/mmx64.efi
3ef1fbaf89bb4141a06ee06b1db9ca8f   sda2/grub_arch/grubx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgarch-arch_root : is-os,    64, pacman, no-docgrub, grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub,    not-far
mapper/vgarch-arch_home : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgarch-arch_root : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
mapper/vgarch-arch_home : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/vgarch-arch_root : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
mapper/vgarch-arch_home : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 7B055726-9B69-4E1B-9DD6-4762B556617D
          Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1       2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
sda2       4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
sda3    1054720 233877503 232822784  111G Linux filesystem
sda4  233877504 500117503 266240000  127G Linux LVM
Disk mapper/vgarch-arch_root: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Disk mapper/vgarch-arch_home: 110.95 GiB, 119130816512 bytes, 232677376 sectors
Disk sdb: 7.24 GiB, 7775191040 bytes, 15185920 sectors
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0
        Start      End Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  9828451 9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  9828452  9838519   10068  4.9M EFI System
sdb3  9838520  9839119     600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  9842688 15185856 5343169  2.5G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:256GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA LITEON LMH-256V2:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:540MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:540MB:120GB:119GB:ext4::;
4:120GB:256GB:136GB:::lvm;
sdb:7775MB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ADATA USB Flash Drive:;
1:32.8kB:5032MB:5032MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5032MB:5037MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5037MB:5038MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:5039MB:7775MB:2736MB:ext4::;
mapper/vgarch-arch_home:119GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:119GB:119GB:ext4::;
mapper/vgarch-arch_root:17.2GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:17.2GB:17.2GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                 FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                   
├─sda1                                                                  0b56d3c5-5f49-4918-b03e-a74ac1b4a646                          
├─sda2               vfat        BD1A-71EF                              b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2                          EFI System Partition
├─sda3               ext4        e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706   617bf50b-b498-48b2-857d-9537226c4a72                          
└─sda4               LVM2_member JWq8ac-3jR4-Ey1E-2mw0-EmPJ-YPVe-dPVeR8 763ae511-8ba2-400a-8cca-0e4126bfa1a0                          
  ├─vgarch-arch_root ext4        394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c                                                                 
  └─vgarch-arch_home ext4        12ca58df-3d30-436e-95ff-cc4c42c6e7a2                                                                 
sdb                  iso9660     2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                                                      Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1               iso9660     2023-08-08-01-19-05-00                 f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2               vfat        F7DB-4D56                              f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                                                  f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0                          Gap1
└─sdb4               ext4        913a515f-213d-4b90-954b-51e9103431ed   424ba32d-f6fd-a74e-87e0-cb7c55af8ef6 writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-09-23.0/crash]   2.3G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-09-23.0/log]     2.3G   0% /var/log
/dev/mapper/vgarch-arch_home                                  103.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgarch-arch_home
/dev/mapper/vgarch-arch_root                                   12.7G  14% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgarch-arch_root
/dev/sda2                                                     505.7M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                      84.5G  17% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
vgarch-arch_home
vgarch-arch_root

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-33-generic   e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic   e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
Arch Linux

========================== sda3/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=BD1A-71EF  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  78.407356262 = 84.189257728   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
   2.705089569 = 2.904567808    boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   9.759067535 = 10.478718976   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  10.729740143 = 11.520970752   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic                  1
   9.759067535 = 10.478718976   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic                  2
  10.729740143 = 11.520970752   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  15.446777344 = 16.585850880   boot/initrd.img                                1
   4.538490295 = 4.873166848    boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic               2
  15.446777344 = 16.585850880   boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic               1
   4.538490295 = 4.873166848    boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17 05:35 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   467 Sep 20 18:47 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Sep 19 23:23 backup

========================== sda3/etc/grub.d/40_custom ===========================

#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above
menuentry 'Arch Linux' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c rw
    initrd /boot/initramfs.linux-lts.img
}


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/vgarch-arch_root: UUID="394db06d-01e3-43a3-bf84-22f7bca2cc0c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vgarch-arch_home: UUID="12ca58df-3d30-436e-95ff-cc4c42c6e7a2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="BD1A-71EF" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="b6110742-692a-45ec-9745-393729ff51e2"
/dev/sda3: UUID="e5d44bf3-db5f-40ff-bd31-ca7c932bc706" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="617bf50b-b498-48b2-857d-9537226c4a72"
/dev/sdb1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2023-08-08-01-19-05-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876e-c8245af921e0"
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="writable" UUID="913a515f-213d-4b90-954b-51e9103431ed" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="424ba32d-f6fd-a74e-87e0-cb7c55af8ef6"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="F7DB-4D56" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876d-c8245af921e0"
/dev/sda4: UUID="JWq8ac-3jR4-Ey1E-2mw0-EmPJ-YPVe-dPVeR8" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="763ae511-8ba2-400a-8cca-0e4126bfa1a0"
/dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="f45e2fa1-c5a6-4d79-876c-c8245af921e0"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="0b56d3c5-5f49-4918-b03e-a74ac1b4a646"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "vgarch" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgarch" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgarch/arch_root' [16.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgarch/arch_home' [<110.95 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi of
mapper/vgarch-arch_root,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Arch Linux (rolling) entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: Sorry mabe stupid comment. I see a raw BIOS boot and an uefi filesystem. Are both  OS installed in same mode?

Comment: If both are in same boot mode, then have you installed in Ubuntu lvm2 driver? `
sudo apt-get install lvm2`  Rather than try to directly boot with full boot stanza, in 40_custom try a configfile entry to the grub in Arch's boot partition. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13788092#post13788092 See 6.5 on configfile details
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Comment: @nobody no they are not, as it shows Ubuntu is installed on efi mode, honestly i thought the laptop BIOS is installed on `/dev/sda1` thats why i didn't try to delete it.

Comment: @oldfred lvm2 installed on both os, and no they aren't on the same boot mode, ubuntu is on efi mode and arch on non-eufi mode (i thought that would be more simpler to use one efi partition for both os).

Comment: UEFI systems can only boot in one mode from start. So once you start in UEFI mode, you cannot switch. Some boot managers are able to force reboot & switch modes, but grub cannot. With Ubuntu you just need to reinstall grub in UEFI mode to convert BIOS install to UEFI install. I would expect you can do the same with Arch, but do  not know details.

Comment: @oldfred Actually i've just turned arch to uefi mode by installing its own grub on /dev/sda2, now i have two booting options, booting from ubuntu's grub or arch's. Please see the last edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Ubuntu grub to recognize dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738956/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-grub-to-recognize-dual-boot)

Comment: Make sure LVM is enabled. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred here's the link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3wzK2CMQXZ/,  if i understood the report, grub is running on BIOS and looks for core.img which is launching grub from ubuntu partition while LVM is disabled, and thats why i got the unkown filesystem error?

Comment: @karel thanks for your suggestion, actually that's the approach I am considering to detect what I've missed.

Comment: @oldfred LVM is now enabled and i've checked from grub rescue `lsmod --builtin`

Comment: Do not know LVM, but you have grub installed in BIOS & UEFI boot mode for Ubuntu. It looks like most recent is BIOS as the mount of the ESP is commented out in fstab. Line 216 But Arch is installed in UEFI boot mode. Both installs need to be UEFI. And system set to default to UEFI boot and all repair, USB flash drives always booted in UEFI mode. No BIOS boots which just confuse things.

Comment: so can i safely delete /dev/sda1 ? Also, reinstalling grub from arch on `/dev/sda2` seems two work, each grub its booting or different OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently running os-prober from arch side detected ubuntu, here's how to do it:

-Boot to Arch Linux from a live cd and connect to the network. using `iwctl`

-Mount partition of logical volume containing root system `/dev/vgarch/arch_root` in my case.

`$mount /dev/vgarch/arch_root /mnt`

-chroot to the mounted partition
`$arch-chroot /mnt`

-install grub package on the system using `pacman -S grub dosfstools os-prober mtools`

-now mount ESP partition to */boot/EFI* directory (create one if doesn't exist using `mkdir /boot/EFI`)

`$mount /dev/sda2 /boot/EFI`

-install grub on EFI partition

`rub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/EFI --bootloader-id=ARCH --recheck` 
-make sure os-prober is enabled and update grub

`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

-exit chroot and reboot, then boot from ARCH entry, the new installed grub will detect ubuntu os and you can make it your default bootloader from boot sequence priority.