# No boot option after installing xubuntu 14.04.3-desktop-amd64

Tags: boot, xubuntu, uefi, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 on my Toshiba P50-B notebook. After installation and reboot, the machine boots into windows without showing boot options. I read a lot about Ubuntu and UEFI and made sure that:

- W10 fast startup is off
- I boot the USB install. media in UEFI mode (initial ubuntu menu is textual, not graphical)

  - i turned secure boot off in bios

While installing, i made sure, that ubuntu chose the EFI partition. When i click "change" on it, it was selected as EFI boot partition.
I used boot repair disc afterwards, but didnt help me too.
 where can be the problem?

thanks!

Comment: Give the output of `lsblk -f`. So we could give specific instructions to repair grub.

Answer (score 1):

As you described in your question you already disabled Fast Boot in Windows ... please re-check !

You have to disable hibernation as well - open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Now **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

Boot into **BIOS** and select **Ubuntu** in **UEFI settings** to be the **default operating system** to boot.

In case the GRUB boot menu doesn't appear when starting the computer :

**Reinstall the GRUB boot loader** to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

**Boot from the Ubuntu installation media** - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sd*
    update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To check and verify the partition numbers use **GParted** (included in the Ubuntu install media).
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Comment: +1 for `for i in` : ) Why is it necessary to bind both `/dev` and `/dev/pts`? Mounting `/dev` would mount `dev/pts` also right?

Comment: @reversiblean : The commands are taken from : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Boot_repair_after_a_Windows_Upgrade_on_Ubuntu_14.04_.28non-RAID.29 :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't help.
I disabled hibernation, than setting Fast Boot option in Windows disappeared, i hope its disabled than. 
Than I executed the commands you proposed. No error message. Group said linux kernel found, windows boot efi found, addind linux ....  I dont see any option in BIOS to select ubuntu. i can only choose if i want boot mode UEFI, or CSM

Comment: @george : You are very close to get it working. - There must be an option in BIOS ... maybe you have to enable or switch something before - I saw this in other cases as well ... so please search and try again ! :)

Comment: In my TOSHIBA P50-B-10P thre is really no BIOS option regarding UEFI other than to choose btw. UEFI and CSM.
 I checked with efibootmgr and the boot order was wrong. Windows was before ubuntu. I changed the order and rebooted - > black screen. Tahn i turned the pc off. When i turned it on, windows booted again. When i checked the boot order later, it was again like before with windows before linux.

Comment: @george : As this a hardware and not an Ubuntu related thing (every vendor has different settings options) - did you check the CSM options ... maybe switching something there ? :)

Comment: @ cl-netbox SOLVED:
You're right, its a hardware thing. My BIOS doesn't implement UEFI in the right way. It ignores EFI entries and always boots the same entry - bootx64.efi , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/549647/uefi-machine-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-through-nvram-bootcatalog-how-to-fix . So i manually created efi image for ubuntu with grub-mkimage and create grub.cfg  as described in the link i pasted here (without the last menuentry). Now everythings ok! i can boot both ubuntu and windows.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
You're right, its a hardware thing. My BIOS doesn't implement UEFI in the right way. It ignores EFI entries and always boots the same entry - bootx64.efi , see [UEFI machine doesn't boot Ubuntu through NVRAM bootcatalog. How to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549647/uefi-machine-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-through-nvram-bootcatalog-how-to-fix) . So i manually created efi image for ubuntu with grub-mkimage and create grub.cfg  as described in the link i pasted here (without the last menuentry). Now everythings ok! i can boot both ubuntu and windows.