# Booting from usb, isoloopback method, Grub2 doesn't find modules

Tags: grub2, uefi, live-usb

I am trying to install ubuntu from a usb stick on a uefi environment.  I have previously succeded following the iso-loopback method explained at [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)

Now I have the following problem.  If I use the Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 amd64 iso, I can boot ubuntu from the live usb stick.  But in all the different laptops that I have tried using the 16.04.1 iso, I end up with a grub command line.  When I try to invoke the loopback command I get

```
grub> loopback loop [path_to_iso]
error: can't find command 'loopback'
```

and `insmod loopback` doesn't find the loopback.mod file.

I have disabled secure boot.  The md5sums for the iso images are correct.  Using the 16.04 iso image works well, but the 16.04.1 doesn't.  I am copying the files to a freshly formatted usb stick.

I want to boot from the 16.04.1 image to reduce the amount of downloads when updating.  Would you please suggest how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: looback? or is that typo just in your post?

Comment: Did you set variable root  to the disk and partition containing the grub files?

Comment: @oldfred  It is a typo.  I couldn't copy and paste, since it was the startup screen.

Comment: @ubfan1 I am trying to set up a dual boot along Windows 10.  On the partitions on the hard drive of the computer there is no grub at all.  I am trying to boot from a usb-stick.   Since I am using the loopback method, I have no access to the file tree and I can't set the root variable to the grub folder on the iso image.

Comment: I have used loopback method to directly boot ISO from BIOS & UEFI flash drives and HDD. But issue  almost always is getting path correct. And with UEFI, I typical have a full install of Ubuntu on larger flash drive. But have directly installed grub for UEFI and manually created my own grub.cfg This was my old BIOS version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484 & Have not tried this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/549647/uefi-machine-doesnt-boot-ubuntu-through-nvram-bootcatalog-how-to-fix

Comment: The root should be to the USB, something like set root='hd0,msdos1'  That should let grub find its modules, then then loopback command should work.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I gave up using the loopback method.  I tried setting up root to (hd0), which was the usb stick, but it kept complaining that it didn't find its modules.  I had compiled the `grubx64.efi` by hand and it works with older iso's.  It doesn't with 16.04.1.  I have now used ubuntu startup disk creator and though I ended up again at the grub prompt, I was now able to set root to the appropriate folder on the file tree.  Ubuntu 16.04.1 is now being installed.

Comment: Nevertheless, I am very curious about why grub finds its modules on older iso's, and doesn't find them with this specific 16.04.1 image.